# Not able to get Azure VM private IP using Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I am trying to write the Private IP address of virtual machine created by Ansible into host inventory. However, I wasn't able to find Azure private IP property for Ansible.

Below is the code that I am using to fetch the private IP of remote host but Ansible is not fetching any private IP of remote host

```
- name: Create virtual network inteface card
  azure_rm_networkinterface:
    resource_group: apache-corp
    name: ansibleServerNIC
    virtual_network: ansibleServerVnet
    subnet: ansibleServerSubnet
    public_ip_name: ansibleServerPublicIP
    security_group: ansibleNetworkSecurityGroup
  register: network_interface

- name: show private_ip
  debug: "{{ network_interface.ip_configuration.private_ip_address }}"
```

Error that Ansible shows:

```
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ip_configuration'\n\nT
```

Comment: Can you update the question with entire playback i.e how are you getting all the azure ip's .by the look of output_ip_address is a custom variable then why are you using .facts with it

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I use:

```
- name: Get network interface details
  azure_rm_networkinterface_facts:
    resource_group: "{{vm.resource_group}}"
    name: "{{vm.network_interface}}"
    profile: "{{vm.azure_profile}}"
  register: azure_networkinterfaces
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: print internal IP
  debug: msg="{{vm.vm_name}} internal ip is {{azure_networkinterfaces.ansible_facts.azure_networkinterfaces[0].properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress}}"

- name: set value of vm internal IP
  set_fact:
    vm_internal_ip: "{{azure_networkinterfaces.ansible_facts.azure_networkinterfaces[0].properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress}}"
```

Comment: Please add some more details on why this work/the approach used or any links/references.

Comment: Tried this code and it works on Ansible 2.8 - seems like a reasonable approach

Answer (score 1):

I had to use little different code as I couldn't get the example working for some reason.

```
- name: Get facts for one network interface
  azure_rm_networkinterface_info:
    resource_group: "{{ vm_resource_group }}"
    name: "{{ vm_name }}-nic"
  register: networkinterface_output

- name: set value of vm internal IP
  set_fact:
    vm_internal_ip: "{{ networkinterface_output.networkinterfaces[0].ip_configurations[0].private_ip_address}}"
```

Hopefully this helps someone.
Ansible, [networkinterface_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_networkinterface_info_module.html)