# ansible failed with 'dict object' has no attribute 'ipAddress

Tags: azure, ansible

I was trying to provision an Azure application gateway by referring to the below document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/application-gateway-configure?tabs=ansible but instead of containers I have used a virtual machine as my backend pool.

```
- name: Get info of backend server 1
  azure_rm_resource_info:
    api_version: '2018-04-01'
    resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
    provider: compute
    resource_type: virtualmachines
    resource_name: "{{ vm_1_name }}"
  register: vm_1_output


- name: Create instance of Application Gateway
  azure_rm_appgateway:
    resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
    name: "{{ appgw_name }}"
    frontend_ip_configurations:
      - public_ip_address: "publicip-{{env}}-{{appgw_name}}"
        name: appGatewayFrontendIP
    frontend_ports:
      - port: 80
        name: appGatewayFrontendPort
    backend_address_pools:
      - backend_addresses:
          - ip_address: "{{ vm_1_output.response[0].properties.ipAddress.ip }}"
        name: appGatewayBackendPool
```

But am getting the below error.

```
"The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ipAddress'\n\nThe error appears to be in
```

I have tried changing the values IpAddress.ip, IPAddress.ip and private_ip_address.id but but still failing. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to post a sample data structure of `vm_1_output`? Or if you have done a `debug` of it, to drill down to the contents of `response[0].properties`? Does it have a key `ipAddress`?

Comment: Any luck with this? Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [return values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_resource_info_module.html#return-values) for the `azure_rm_resource_info` module in Ansible, there doesn't seem to be an `ipaddress` property being returned in the response.

Use the [azure_rm_networkinterface_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/azure_rm_networkinterface_info_module.html#azure-rm-networkinterface-info-module) module to get facts for the network interface attached to the VM for retrieving the [IP address](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/azure_rm_networkinterface_info_module.html#return-networkinterfaces/ip_configurations). You should then be able to get to the IP with an expression similar to: `networkinterface_output.networkinterfaces[0].ip_configurations[0].private_ip_address`

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501209/not-able-to-get-azure-vm-private-ip-using-ansible) SO post that discusses a similar issue.